# Oracle 12c - Issue in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, for-loop, oracle12c

I have the following block of code:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c_cursor IS
    SELECT *
    FROM   table_a;

    FOR i IN c_cursor LOOP
    IF i.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table_b WHERE ind_val='Y')
     THEN
      BEGIN
        INSERT INTO val_table_err
        VALUES (''ERROR:id''|| i.id,
                1,
                1,
                NULL,
                1,
                i.type_cd);
      END;
    END IF;
    END LOOP;
```

I am getting the error `PLS-00405: SUBQUERY NOT ALLOWED IN THIS CONTEXT`

Any help to resolve this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: issue is easy to spot... if i.id not in (subquery) isn't valid. I think it's something along the lines of if exists select id from table_B where ind_valu = 'y' and i.id = b.id (but I'm not fully familiar with 12c). Side question....why do this as a cursor? One statement without a loop is far better

Comment: There is a lot of other code using the cursor in the pl/sql script. Should've mentioned that.

Comment: Why are you using PL/SQL in the first place? This can be done much more efficiently with one simple insert statement: `insert into val_table_err select ... from table_a where a.id not in (select id from table_b where ind_val = 'Y')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do a `NOT IN` like that in any version of Oracle.

It would generally make sense to put the `NOT IN` clause into your cursor definition.  Assuming that `NOT IN` rather than `NOT EXISTS` is the more efficient approach, something like this would work.

```
CURSOR c_cursor IS
    SELECT *
    FROM   table_a a
    WHERE  a.id NOT IN (SELECT b.id
                          FROM table_b b
                         WHERE ind_val = 'Y');
```

If you really want the check to be done within the loop, you'd need a different construction.  You could do something like

```
FOR i IN c_cursor 
LOOP
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
    INTO l_cnt
    FROM table_b b
   WHERE b.id = i.id
     AND b.ind_val = 'Y';

  IF( l_cnt = 0 )
  THEN
    <<do something>>
  END IF;
END LOOP;
```

Of course, this won't be as efficient or as clear as filtering out the loans in the cursor in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing related to your Oracle version, I got the same error in 11g, because you can't use NOT IN and a subquery inside an IF statement.

Here's my test case:

```
create table table_a (idA number);
create table table_b (idB number);

insert into table_a values(1);
insert into table_a values(2);
insert into table_b values(1);
commit;
```

This anonymous pl/sql block gets the same error as yours:

```
DECLARE
  i number;
  CURSOR c_cursor IS
    SELECT idA
    FROM   table_a;
begin
    FOR i IN c_cursor LOOP
    IF i NOT IN (SELECT idB FROM table_b)
     THEN
        dbms_output.put_line(i);
    END IF;
    END LOOP; 
end;
/
```

Try something like this instead:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c_cursor IS
    SELECT idA, idB
    FROM   table_a a left join table_b on idA=idB;
  i c_cursor%rowtype;
begin
    FOR i IN c_cursor LOOP
    IF i.idB is null
     THEN
        dbms_output.put_line(i.idA);
    END IF;
    END LOOP; 
end;
/
```

It has the benefit of letting oracle choose the join algorithm, instead of doing a nested loop yourself.